# Going through possible completions with the keyboard

Tags: completion

I am using `M-x galaxy TAB` to display minibuffer commands.  I get a temporary *Completions* buffer that says

```
Click on a completion to select it.
```

The above means that I cannot complete or go through the possibilities in the minibuffer, but am being forced to use the mouse.

What can I do so that I can use the keyboard to go through the possible completions?

Comment: You can do exactly what @FranBurstall describes in his answer. BTW, I do that all the time.

Comment: Emacs could do us a favour and switch to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*Completions*` buffer is a buffer like any other: you can switch to it (`C-x o` a couple of times, though maybe there is something more efficient) and then navigate with the usual keys `C-n/p` or arrow-keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type the next character to get a smaller set of (or a unique) candidates, then press `Tab` again, in order to complete via keyboard. The next character to be typed is marked in **bold**.

Another option would be to use a different [minibuffer input completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion) framework. Those are more comfortable than the standard one.
There are multiple available:

- [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) (extra package, install through MELPA)
- [helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) (extra package, install through MELPA)
- [vertico](https://github.com/minad/vertico) (extra package, install through MELPA)
- icomplete-vertical-mode (a built in one, enable with `M-x icomplete-vertical-mode`)
- ido (another built in one, enable with `M-x ido-mode`)
- [icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) (extra package, download source and load it yourself in order to install it)

Comment: There is also `icomplete` that lets me move from one possibility to another.  Does `icomplete-vertical-mode` immediately allow me to navigate the completion possibilities with the arrow keys?